# One Dimensional Array to Multidimensional Array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

How do I transfer the values from the one dimensional first array to the multidimensional second array so that the order of numbers is like the one in the second array?

```
double[] first = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

double[,] second = 
{
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
    {3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
    {4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
    {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
}
```

Comment: Thinking of this for instance, second[0, 0] = first[0], .. and so on. There must be a better solution.

Comment: @Emcho do that until you determine the pattern

Comment: As a starting point make a for loop counting up to `first.length - 5` (5 being the length of each multidimentional row), then `TakeRange` from `i` to `i+4` and add this to multi dimentional array defined as `double[5, first.Length - 5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int indexModifier = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Math.sqrt(second.Length); ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Math.sqrt(second.Length); ++j)
    {
        second[j + indexModifier, j] = first[i + indexModifier);
    }
    ++indexModifier;
}
```

Comment: What is the variable col here exactly ?